# Is canceling an asyncTask expensive?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

So if I have 5 asynctasks running and I cancel them the UI freezes a little bit, but if I do 20 asyncTasks and cancel them then my UI freezes for a noticeable time.  My question is, is the asyncTask.cancel(true) method expensive?  Is that way my UI is freezing? I noticed that when I do not call cancel that my UI does not freeze.  Is there anyway I can prevent my UI from freezing?  I tried putting the .cancel(true) method in it's own thread, but that did not help.

Here some code.

```
     //could be as little as 1 or could be 20
    for( AsyncTask asyncTask : asyncTasks )
    {
        if ( asyncTask != null )
        {
            //seems to block UI for a bit if there are a lot of calls
            asyncTask.cancel( true );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code in the onCancelled() callback of your tasks?

Comment: Yes I do, but it seems like if I comment out the call back and run the app.  The same delay happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the cancel call I was logging the object, which uses the jackson library.  It re instantiated

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
```

every time I wanted to use this method.  Thus, I just  instantiated new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter(); once and it fixed the lag on the UI I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Does your task check the [`isCancelled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) in your `doInBackground()` function?

[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s are meant to run quickly (i.e. computationally short tasks) in the background and post results to the UI thread. This means that when you make a call to `asyncTask.cancel(true);`, instead of  [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) being invoked on the UI thread, [`onCancelled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29) is invoked on the UI thread.

Since the 'cancelling' is invoked on the UI thread, if your thread is in a tight loop and doesn't make any checks to any global variables or cancel requests (like checking [`isCancelled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29)), it might take a 'bit of time' for the underlying API to clean up your thread (properly end/cancel it without your thread ending itself), that 'bit of time' is the UI 'pause' you experience.

To alleviate this, in your [`doInBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) function, just make a check for the `isCancelled` function:

```
// simple example function:
protected Void doInBackground (Void... params) {
    for(int i=0; i < 65535; ++i) {
        if (isCancelled()) { break; } // exit loop on cancel request
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this `AsyncTask` if we then call `asyncTask.cancel(true);`, the loop will break on the next check of `isCancelled` and the UI thread can continue vs. waiting for the loop to finish it's iterations (thus 'pausing' the UI until the thread has completed).

Hope that can help.